# Azure B2C Account Creation via custom policy AAD Write creates the user as locked

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create a sign in flow with just in time migration. Upon verifying user via REST API I need to write the user to directory via AAD Write validation technical profile. It works fine but it creates the accounts as "locked" - when I go in to portal I see "Block Sign in= YES"

What could be the reason? I use the same technical profile and it works fine on the sign up flow

Below is the technical profile I execute within the local sign in technical profile

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-Migrate">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />  

      </InputClaims>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->

          <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />   

        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
        <!-- Optional claims. -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" /> 
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_companyId" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_companyName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_communicationOptin" /> 
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" /> 
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Is this called from the self asserted technical profile that also collects the password? Or is the password collected in a different technical profile than the one that calls this?

Comment: To add to @JasSuri's comment, if you create a new account without a password value, then I believe it's created as disabled.

Comment: Thank you - password claim was the issue. I will post the answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

```
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
```

...

It turns out the "newpassword" claim is not available since the claim I was collecting during the self assertion sign in step is "password". Adding the "PartnerClaimType=password" did not copy the "password" into the "newpassword" claim as well.

The solution was to simply rename "newpassword" to "password" and the flow worked fine

```
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
```

As Chris commented when the password is not there AAD Write still creates the user but creates it as disabled - which in my opinion should not happen and B2C should give a meaningful error message